# How to pass None keyword as command line argument

Tags: python

I am trying to pass `None` keyword as a command line parameter to a script as follows, if I explicity mention `Category=None` it works but the moment I switch to `sys.argv[1]` it fails, any pointers on how to fix this?

```
category = None --> works
#category=sys.argv[1] --> doesn't work
```

so I tried as below which still didn't work

```
  if sys.argv[1].strip()==None:
    category = None
else:
    category=sys.argv[1].strip()
```

Command line passage:

```
 script.py None
```

Comment: `sys.argv[1]` is a string.  `None` is not.  Try `if sys.argv[1].strip()=='None':`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just an FYI. You can use **[ast module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html)** to convert sting 'None' to None type

**Ex:**

```
import ast
if not ast.literal_eval(sys.argv[1]):
    print "Input Arg is None"
```

or

```
if sys.argv[1].strip() == 'None':
     print "Input Arg is None"
```

*Faster and better solution.*

Answer (score 28):

As Stephen mentioned, `None` is not a string, so when comparing a `str` type to a `NoneType` type, the result will always be `False`.

If I just put `"` around `None` on the right-hand-side of the comparison, we get:

```
import sys

if sys.argv[1].strip() == "None":
    category = None
else:
    category = sys.argv[1].strip()

print(category)
print(type(category))
```

Resulting in:

```
~/temp $ python script.py 123
123
<type 'str'>
~/temp $ python script.py None
None
<type 'NoneType'>
```

#### `argparse` instead?

However, I recommend using [argparse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) instead, if you're in a position to do so. I use it all the time.

The above code could be replaced with:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Do some cool stuff.')

def none_or_str(value):
    if value == 'None':
        return None
    return value

parser.add_argument('category', type=none_or_str, nargs='?', default=None,
                    help='the category of the stuff')

args = parser.parse_args()

print(args.category)
print(type(args.category))
```

Which will also tolerate no parameters

```
~/temp $ python script.py 
None
<type 'NoneType'>
~/temp $ python script.py 123
123
<type 'str'>
~/temp $ python script.py None
None
<type 'NoneType'>
```

And it auto-formats some help text for you!

```
~/temp $ python script.py --help
usage: script.py [-h] [category]

Do some cool stuff.

positional arguments:
  category    the category of the stuff

optional arguments:
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit
```

Comment: Helpful answer.

Comment: is `type=none_or_str` a valid argument for argparse ? shouldn't be `type=str, default=None` instead?

Comment: @FaridAlijani: both are valid, but `type=str` does not answer the original question. Try both and see what happens 

Answer (score 3):

I think more appropriate way to do this would be to check if there's any parameter passed or not. If not then set `category` to `None`, otherwise set the value that is passed.

Ex:

```
if len(sys.argv) == 2: // or >= 2 in case of more parameter
    category = sys.argv[1].strip()
else:
    category = None
```

So if you just call `script.py`, category will be set to `None`.
If you call like `script.py Value`, category will be set to `Value`.

Answer (score -1):

Piggybacking on @FraggaMuffin's answer, you may use a lambda function for convenience. Thus, instead of

```py
parser.add_argument('category', type=none_or_str, nargs='?', default=None,
                    help='the category of the stuff')
```

You may write

```py
parser.add_argument('category', type=lambda x : None if x == 'None' else str(x), nargs='?', default=None,
                    help='the category of the stuff')
```

This is for convenience, if you do not want to write separate functions such as none_or_str, none_or_int, etc.